# Python: Adding values in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Using a while loop, I'm prompting the user to enter 5 different numbers and trying to create a total of those numbers. How would I be able to create that total?

This is my code so far

```
count = 1


while count < 5:
    count += 1
    int(input("Enter a value: "))
```

Comment: The same way you are updating `count` to track the number of iterations.

Comment: Hint: before the loop create a variable called `total` and initialize to `0`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count = 1
total = 0

while count < 5:
    count += 1
    total += int(input("Enter a value: "))

print (total)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution that is smaller and using a for loop

```
total = 0
for i in range(5):
        total += int(input("Enter Value : "))
print(f'Your Total is : {total}')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page, especially the part about making sure that your answer actually addresses the question posed. Here, by changing the while-loop to the for-loop, you are changing the requirement.