# Trying to calculate the sum of numbers using while loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the sum of multiple numbers using a while loop. When a negative number is entered the sum of the numbers should be printed. When I run the code all it does is print the last positive number entered. Here is the current non-working code:

```
sum = 0
number = 1
while number > 0:
    number = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    if number > 0:
        tot = sum + number
print("The sum of the numbers is", tot)
```

Comment: This is a case where rubber duck debugging should work. Please try it out!

Comment: Make for yourself two seperate variables, one with the user input, and one with the current sum. This will help you to seperate them from each other.

Comment: `tot = sum + number` > `sum = sum + number`. And print `sum`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Adding values in a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026355/python-adding-values-in-a-while-loop)

Comment: `tot` is a new variable here. You just need to update `sum`. So instead of `tot = sum + number` you'd do `sum = sum + number` and replace the `tot` in `print` statement too with `sum`. And btw, please use a different variable name for `sum`. I will leave it as an exercise for you why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because sum is always 0 - try this instead;

```
tot = 0
number = 1
while number > 0:
    number = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    if number > 0:
        tot = tot + number
print("The sum of the numbers is", tot)
```

Answer (score 3):

You keep modifying a variable called `tot` but it gets overwritten each time with `sum` (0) plus `number` (the current number).

Instead, add the total to `sum` each time as follows:

```
sum = 0
number = 1
while number > 0:
    number = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    if number > 0:
        sum = sum + number
print("The sum of the numbers is", sum)
```

Now `sum` will keep growing as you enter positive numbers. You don't need the variable `tot` at all!

You can even use this cool "`+=`" operator to increment the value of `sum` directly and save you some typing:

```
sum = 0
number = 1
while number > 0:
    number = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    if number > 0:
        sum += number
print("The sum of the numbers is", sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have confused the variable names `tot` and `sum`.
If you replace `tot` with `sum`, your output will be the correct sum.
This way, `sum` is correctly updated, based on its previous value:

```
sum = 0
number = 1
while number > 0:
    number = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    if number > 0:
        sum = sum + number
print("The sum of the numbers is", sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration you are add the number with the `sum` variable which is initialised as `0`. so need to change the addition expression & add update the sum variable in each iteration with the previous iteration `sum` + the new entered number in each iteration.

**Code :**

```
sum = 0
number = 1
while number > 0:
    number = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
    if number > 0:
        sum = sum + number
print("The sum of the numbers is", sum)
```

**Output :**

[image]